# Why are my bin directories not getting filled with .class files?

Tags: java, directory, bin, .class-file

Im practicing java, and I noticed that in my older projects, my bin directories have "mirror images" of "something.java" files. But now they just dont seem to appear, no matter what I do. Is it a problem? If it is, how should I solve this?
My app is a gui app.
My pom.xml look like this.

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>KisallatNyilvantartoRendszer</groupId>
      <artifactId>KisallatNyilvantartoRendszer</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <org.springframework.version>5.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        </properties>
    <dependencies>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
       <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The project said it couldnt find the ViewController class, so I solved it with this:

```
  fx:controller="KisallatNyilvantartoRendszer.view.ViewController"
```

But now it throws the following problem:

```
 Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/M%c3%a1t%c3%a9/Desktop/Workspace/KisallatNyilvantartoRendszer/target/classes/KisallatNyilvantartoRendszer/allatok.fxml:16

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at KisallatNyilvantartoRendszer.Main.start(Main.java:18)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javafx.scene.control.TableView field KisallatNyilvantartoRendszer.view.ViewController.allatView to javafx.scene.control.TableColumn
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application KisallatNyilvantartoRendszer.Main
```

I also think that my workspace is messed up, cause .class files are not getting created in bin/target folders. Is it a problem? How should I make it work?

Comment: How are you building your project?

Comment: I start a simple Java App and I convert it into a Maven project. Is it a problem?

Comment: @Yasuo22 it's not a problem, but we couldn't know, it's not like a "bin directory" or a "Java App" are a standard thing. So it depends on how your project is built. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant parts of you POM.

Comment: For example, my target bin also contains nothing, so I get the following error: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/M%c3%a1t%c3%a9/Desktop/Workspace/KisallatNyilvantartoRendszer/target/classes/KisallatNyilvantartoRendszer/allatok.fxml:16

Comment: I pretty much tried to ask shortly all my problem, I think it's a bit complicated than a single mistake. Maybe I messed up my Workspace somehow?

Comment: Have you tried https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/maven ?

Comment: I did what your link said. I used the mvn clean run inside my project (in workspace) 
I got the following error message:

Execution default-cli of goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run failed: Unable to load the mojo 'run' in the plugin 'org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/openjfx/JavaFXRunMojo has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0